# Using SimpleMemberShipProvider in Visual Studio 2010 MVC 4 Basic Template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

For quite a long time I've been searching a good guide to develop a MVC 4 application, which would use SimpleMemberShipProvider.

I've created a project with MVC4 Basic template in Visual Studio 2010. So, it gives no Views, Models or controllers. Can you give a step by step procedure of how to make this project use SimpleMemberShip Provider to manage all its user registration, login and forms authentication. All the examples around the `Google` using Visual Studio express 2012. (But, I can't use that for company policy and project requirement.) So, please help out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check here http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Comment: As I said that page also points to Matthew Osborn's blog post which is using Visual Studio Web Express 2012.

Comment: I think `SimpleMembership` ships with `.net framewrk 4.5` and so it may be used only with `Visual Studio 2012`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this comment as an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I don't have VS 2010 handy, but I know that on VS 2012 you can create an MVC4 project with .NET Framework 4.0 and if you use the Internet Application template it will build in all the Simple Membership code.

If doing the above in VS 2010 does not generate the Simple Membership features, maybe you could run VS 2012 long enough to generate the code and then use the VS 2012 code to guide implementing the same features in VS 2010. I think the important part should be the MVC4 Simple Membership, not the particular version of VS.